# Importing neo4j with py2neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I am unable to import 'neo4j' using py2neo. When I do the following;

```
 from py2neo import neo4j
```

I get the error:

```
  cannot import name 'neo4j'
```

My py2neo version is 3.1.2

The output for the following is:

```
dir(py2neo)

['BoltDataSource', 'BoltNode', 'BoltPath', 'BoltRelationship', 'BoltTransaction', 'ClientError', 'Commander', 'ConstraintError', 'Cursor', 'CypherSyntaxError', 'CypherTypeError', 'CypherWriter', 'DBMS', 'DataSource', 'DatabaseError', 'Entity', 'Forbidden', 'Graph', 'GraphDatabase', 'GraphError', 'HTTPDataSource', 'HTTPResponse', 'HTTPTransaction', 'JAVA_INTEGER_MAX_VALUE', 'JAVA_INTEGER_MIN_VALUE', 'JSONResponse', 'Mapping', 'NOT_FOUND', 'Node', 'NodeSelection', 'NodeSelector', 'OrderedDict', 'PRODUCT', 'PULL_ALL', 'Path', 'PropertyDict', 'RUN', 'Record', 'Relatable', 'Relationship', 'RemoteEntity', 'ReprIO', 'Resource', 'ResourceTemplate', 'Response', 'Schema', 'ServerAddress', 'ServerAuth', 'ServerError', 'ServerPlugin', 'SetView', 'StringIO', 'Subgraph', 'ThreadLocalEntityCache', 'Transaction', 'TransactionFinished', 'TransientError', 'UNAUTHORIZED', 'URI', 'Unauthorized', 'UnmanagedExtension', 'Walkable', 'Watcher', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__copyright__', '__doc__', '__email__', '__file__', '__license__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'auth', 'authenticate', 'b64encode', 'basic_auth', 'bolt_hydrate', 'caching', 'cast', 'cast_node', 'cast_relationship', 'chain', 'client_errors', 'coerce_atomic_property', 'coerce_property', 'compat', 'cypher', 'cypher_escape', 'cypher_repr', 'cypher_request', 'database', 'deprecated', 'deque', 'ext', 'get_auth', 'get_http_headers', 'getenv', 'http', 'integer', 'is_collection', 'json_dumps', 'keyring', 'main', 'mktime_tz', 'normalise_request', 'order', 'packages', 'parsedate_tz', 'raise_from', 'register_server', 'relationship_case', 'remote', 'round_robin', 'selection', 'set_http_header', 'size', 'snake_case', 'status', 'stdout', 'string', 'types', 'unicode', 'update_stats_keys', 'user_agent', 'ustr', 'util', 'uuid4', 'version_tuple', 'walk', 'warn', 'watch', 'webbrowser', 'xstr']
```

How do I import neo4j from py2neo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think you can import neo4j from py2neo? Look carefully in py2neo documentation: http://py2neo.org/v3/

Your import statement should look something like `from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship, authenticate`

Comment: I was trying to understand code written by a previous member of the project I am working on where neo4j has been imported from py2neo. It can also be seen here : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75842/optimizing-for-data-import-in-neo4j-using-py2neo

Comment: It's for older version of py2neo, I think it's not even py2neo 2, maybe py2neo 1.6. You are using py2neo3.

Comment: So is the "Graph" import a replacement for the "neo4j" from earlier versions?

Comment: Not really. Read about the differences from Nigel Small himself: https://neo4j.com/blog/py2neo-2-0-unleashed/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I didn't the right place to look for it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create nodes relationship with tradtional codeing way you can create it with importing the Node, Relationship, Graph, etc from py2neo like:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship, authenticate
```

But if you want to execute cypher queries you need neo4j to be installed and import it on you code

install neo4j with pip

> pip install neo4j

```
import neo4j

driver = neo4j.GraphDatabase.driver('bolt://localhost',auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "Password1"))

def get_db():
    if not hasattr(g, 'neo4j_db'):
        g.neo4j_db = driver.session()
    return g.neo4j_db

db = get_db()
results = db.run("MATCH (movie_1:Movie) "
                 "WHERE movie_1.title =~ {title} "
                 "RETURN movie", {"title": "(?i).*" + q + ".*"}
```